# Losing files in camel when consuming with multiple threads

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel 2.11.1

Have such route:

```
from("file:///somewhere/").
 threads(20).
 to("direct:process")
```

Some time I'm getting this exception: `org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException` with message

```
No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: GenericFile[/somewhere/file.txt] of type: 
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile on: file.txt. Caused by: Error during type conversion from type: 
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile to the required type: byte[] with value GenericFile[/somewhere/file.txt] 
due java.io.FileNotFoundException: /somewhere/file.txt (No such file or directory).
```

Since I'm seeing lot of .camelLock files in the directory, I assume this happens due to attempt of few threads to process same file. How to avoid that?

**UPDATE 1**

Tried to use `scheduledExecutorService` and remove `threads(20)`. Seems I'm losing fewer files, but still losing them. How to avoid? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you do in direct:process?
And what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linux. Actually in direct:process just reading the file and working with my internal beans.

Comment: got same issue, some files are deleted. I can see process is strated from logs, but then cannot find in any error, done or in current folder. Totally gone

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue, mine was 2 file processors retrieving from same directory. Result: Losing all my files.

**Here is the scenario:**

- `Thread#1` retrieves `file1`, moves to `process` folder
- `Thread#2` retrieves same file: `file1` at the same time. `file1` is deleted
- `Thread#2` cannot find `file1` in `source` directory, rename fails.
- `Thread#1` fails due to deleted file by `Thread#2`

**Here is the reason:**

If you check GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.renameFile method, you'll see camel first deletes target file, then renames source file to target. That's why above condition occurs

---

I dont know about a generic solution, either separating source-consumer relation or implement a work distributor mechanism should be implemented.

Sınce your threads live in same JVM, I suggest you to implement a concurrent load distributor. That'd give requester 1 file name at a time in concurrent way

Comment: try use noop=true to avoid move/delete files?